# javascript object.key not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have code to get GA parameters that have been stored in a cookie and make them the values of inputs in a form that isn't working and I can't for the life of me figure out why.

```
(function( $ ) {
    if (Cookies.get('gaParams')) {
        var params = Cookies.get('gaParams');
    }
    $('#source').val(params['utm_source'] ? params['utm_source'] : 'organic');
    $('#medium').val(params['utm_medium'] ? params['utm_medium'] : '');
    $('#campaign').val(params['utm_campaign'] ? params['utm_campaign'] : '');
    $('#keywords').val(params['utm_terms'] ? params['utm_terms'] : '');

    console.log(params,params['utm_medium'],params.utm_medium);

}(jQuery));
```

you can see it in action by going [here](http://yamputours.staging.wpengine.com/?utm_medium=testing&utm_source=whatever) and then clicking on the "request Quote" button.
The console.log will return `{"utm_medium":"testing","utm_source":"whatever"} undefined undefined`

I don't understand why calling the object keys won't give me the values this way.

Comment: have you trying parsing your json data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the variable `params` is string type . You should use this method `JSON.parse()` to parse a JSON string

```
var params = Cookies.get('gaParams');
params = JSON.parse(params);
```